# why android studio don`t build the main activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-activity, android-image

I would like to ask about the following problem

When I opened the Android Studio, it did not automatically build the Main Activity and the Android app icon did not appear Here ( screenshot below )

screenshot

[image]

And I checked the Gradle settings  (picture below)

Gradle Screen shot

[image]

What is the solution to this problem ??

Comment: Select from menu Built/Clean Project  and than select menu  file/Invalidate Catch/Restart

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade the Gradle to the version 6.5 and "Sync Project with Gradle Files". Gradle 6.5+ is to be required to use Android Gradle plugin 4.1+. See [release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle).